# How do you recreate the arc relationship in the Oracle Database Modeler in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm not sure how to write out a foreign key constraint in Oracle APEX that will represent an arc relationship in the Oracle Database Modeler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the datamodeler generate the relational model and the DDL code.  Then, open the SQL script editor in APEX, paste in the DDL code, give the script a name, and execute it - see screen shots below.

**(example) ERD**

[image: ERD]

**Relational model (generated)**

[image: Relational model]

**DDL code (generated)**

[image: DDL code]

**APEX script editor (notice the CHECK constraint enforcing the "arc")**

[image: APEX script editor]

Script executed

[image]

You may have to tweak the script a bit (if there are error messages).

Then, you should do some testing, so that you see that the "arc" actually works eg

**Testing**

```
-- these 3 INSERTs must fail
-- {1} event without a "venue id"
insert into event ( 
  id, eventdate, private_home_id, public_space_id 
) values (
  1, sysdate, null, null
) ;
-- ORA-02290: check constraint (...ARC_1) violated

-- {2} private home does not exist
insert into event ( 
  id, eventdate, private_home_id, public_space_id 
) values (
  1, sysdate, 1000, null
) ;
-- ORA-02291: integrity constraint (...EVENT_PRIVATE_HOME_FK) violated - parent
key not found

-- {3} public space does not exist
insert into event ( 
  id, eventdate, private_home_id, public_space_id 
) values (
  1, sysdate, null, 2000
) ;
-- ORA-02291: integrity constraint (...EVENT_PUBLIC_SPACE_FK) violated - parent
key not found
```

**INSERT some data into the PRIVATE_HOME and PUBLIC_SPACE tables**

```
-- add a PRIVATE_HOME and a PUBLIC_SPACE
insert into private_home( id, vname ) values ( 1000, 'The Manor' ) ;
insert into public_space( id, vname ) values ( 2000, 'Royal Albert Hall' ) ;


-- add 2 events
insert into event ( 
  id, eventdate, private_home_id, public_space_id 
) values (
  1, sysdate, 1000, null
) ;

insert into event ( 
  id, eventdate, private_home_id, public_space_id 
) values (
  2, sysdate, null, 2000
) ;

select * from event ;
SQL> select * from event ;

        ID EVENTDATE PRIVATE_HOME_ID PUBLIC_SPACE_ID
---------- --------- --------------- ---------------
         1 06-MAY-20            1000                
         2 06-MAY-20                            2000
```

Comment: Great answer! The whole point of the relational model is to help you with the ddl.